# On Linux, is it possible to know if disk size was changed without rescanning the disk?

Tags: linux, kernel, disk, vmware, block-device

After changing a disk size in VMware (for example increasing it by 10 more GB), the next step is to rescan it in Linux so that kernel identifies this size change.

For this we use this command:

```
echo 1>/sys/class/block/sda/device/rescan
```

In our scripts, we rescan every couple of minutes from a `cron` job, in order to verify if we need to resize the relevant disks.

I want to know if there is some way to identify if a disk size was changed, without rescanning, and if the disk size was really changed, only then to rescan.

So far we have not found a way to verify if the disk size was changed without rescanning, but we hope we can get answers here.

The reason for my question is that we do not feel comfortable with rescanning every couple of minutes, even though this activity isn't risky.

Reference: https://kerneltalks.com/disk-management/how-to-rescan-disk-in-linux-after-extending-vmware-disk/

Comment: I wonder if the rescanning can have a performance impact, e.g. if disk accesses are blocked for the duration of the rescan. That might be some sort of a problem. But I also wonder how common the resizes are (in your environment)? If they're relatively rare it shouldn't be too tough to have some tool trigger them from the outside. In whatever way you like, having a daemon listen to some network socket, or having a special user or SSH key which you can use to log in over SSH to trigger the rescan and associated actions.

Comment: Actually, that would be something one might think the virtualization environment tools might provide. I don't know if any do, and that starts to sound like a different question.

Comment: @ilkkachu rescans in a virtualised environment are pretty much instantaneous, so while there is a performance impact, it’s minimal (unlike rescans in physical environments which can cause noticeable stalls). And yes, at least some guest integration tools do provide a way of triggering jobs inside the guest from the host (or VM management infrastructure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to identify that a block device has been resized is to rescan it. That’s it. There’s no need to find another way of rescanning the block device in order to decide whether to rescan it.

In a virtualised environment it should be safe to run this every two minutes; there will be a very slight performance hit whenever a rescan is run, because the rescan acquires interrupt locks, but rescanning a virtual block device is very fast. If you’re uncomfortable with rescans every two minutes, you can reduce the frequency — do you really need to react to disk resizes within two minutes?

(Note that some paravirtualised storage drivers automatically update the size seen by the guest, so rescanning isn’t necessary; this is apparently *not* the case for VMware.)

You may want to look at [`open-vm-tools`](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools) which supposedly allows workloads to be triggered inside guests from the host: that way, you could resize the disk externally, and trigger a job inside the guest to rescan and resize the volumes. I’ve never done this so I don’t know if it’s actually possible.

Comment: in case we run it every couple min echo 1>/sys/class/block/sda/device/rescan  , is it safe ?

Comment: @yael that has been answered implicitly by Stephen: He did recommend you do it.